# FORALL......SAVE EXCEPTIONS

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

We are using FORALL.....SAVE EXCEPTIONS.  At the end of the loop, we have this:

```
FOR i IN 1..SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT LOOP<BR><BR>
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR CREATING STAGING TICKER: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));<BR><BR>
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INDEX INFO: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_INDEX);<BR>
END LOOP;
```

Is there any way for me to get at actual VALUES in that array?  Say if a customers email was too long.....for me to actually display the value which caused the error?  Rather than just some index number?

Thanks!

Comment: The `ERROR_INDEX` gives you the index of the original collection that failed.  Can you just go back to that collection to get the actual value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the loop variable `i` to display the content of the `exception` array in your case. See below an example procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1 (V_EMP_ID DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE)
IS
     lv_error_string VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    FORALL INDX IN V_EMP_ID.FIRST..V_EMP_ID.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
    UPDATE EMPLOYEES 
     ---trying to rasie an exception by using a calculation
    SET SALARY=SALARY * 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
    WHERE ID_E= V_EMP_ID(INDX);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS 
    THEN
    FOR i IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
    LOOP
        ---Am printing the value of the exception array.
        dbms_output.put_line('exception Raised for record' ||V_EMP_ID(i));           

    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Ouput:

```
SQL> DECLARE
     empid   DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE;
    BEGIN
     empid (1) := 1;
     empid (2) := 9;

     PROC1 (empid);
   END;  

/
exception Raised for record  1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: But, can I see actual values?  Like the record which caused the issue.  Can I get at those values?

Comment: I printed the actual record itself. If you see my example, i am passing empid as array. And thats only am printing in the exception. If your collection has columns like xyx, then you can use `<yourcollection>(i).xyz` . In my case if it would had been some columns then it would had been `V_EMP_ID(i).emp_id`